# Different SQL commands for different Excel sheets

Tags: sql, excel, vba

With what VBA macro commands can I switch between sheets, in order to execute specific Workbook Connecton SQL commands?

What I have tried is, to select a sheet, write the sheet specific sql command store that command in the specific connection's SQL command and then refresh the workbook to get the result. The code executes only on the sheet that it originally was executed on, not the sheet I selected.

```
Sheets("Alex").Select

' The SQL command text
Dim comText As String
comText = ... // the SQL command text

' Changes the workbook's SQL command text to the text in the code above
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("conCRM").ODBCConnection // conCRM - the name of the conection
    .commandText = comText
End With

' Refreshes data from the database
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("conCRM").Refresh
```

The thing that, in my opinion, is wrong is that the last line in the code targets the whole workbook and not the specific sheet I need.

Comment: Are you trying to store a SQL command on each page, execute that SQL against an external database, and get the results on a different sheet?

Comment: Yes, that is my goal. However, this seems very complex. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is close to what you are trying to do. It takes 3 different SQL statements, adds a sheet for each one, executes it and puts each result on a new sheet.

```
Sub addSQLResultsOnto3Sheets()
    Dim oConn As WorkbookConnection
    Dim oQt As QueryTable
    Dim oSh As Worksheet
    Dim i, SQL

    'Get the existing connection's connection string
    Set oConn = ActiveWorkbook.Connections("conCRM")

    'Three different SQL statements, to be output onto 3 different worksheets.
    SQL = Array("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM MyTable", "SELECT TOP 2 * FROM MyTable", "SELECT TOP 3 * FROM MyTable")

    For i = 0 To 2
        'Add a new sheet "Results N"
        Set oSh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        oSh.Name = "Results " & (i + 1)

        'Add a new sheet with SQL
        Set oQt = oSh.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcExternal, oConn.ODBCConnection.Connection, Destination:=oSh.Range("A1")).QueryTable
        oQt.CommandText = SQL(i)
        oQt.Refresh
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I will have to modify this, but it seems that it will do the trick! Thank you very much, transistor1! :)

Comment: any time! i'm glad to help when i can! :-)